# Как из данного запроса сделать запрос на INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

Есть запрос выводящий определенные значения. Как преобразовать этот запрос в запрос на вставку значения по этой выборке?

```
SELECT TaxGroup FROM Goods g LEFT JOIN GoodsGroups gg ON g.GroupID = gg.ID  WHERE gg.Code like 'AAO%' ORDER by g.ID
```

Грубо говоря я ламер в области `Transact-SQL` и умею только в `SELECT`, не могу понять как из этого сделать `INSERT`

Answer (score 4):

Просто добавьте команду insert перед выполнением select

```
insert into table_name(column_name)
SELECT TaxGroup FROM Goods g LEFT JOIN GoodsGroups gg ON g.GroupID = gg.ID
WHERE gg.Code like 'AAO%' ORDER by g.ID
```